# How to apply CSS and JavaScript from dropbox folder (For using it in blogger)

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to add dropbox url in the below link tags and script tags,so that I can use this template in my blog. I tried it, but the themes are not being applied. Please help. My common dropbox folder: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/b7bqyva7pz39nx1/QIGR6hJpkM contains css and js files.

```
<head>
    <title>Tessellate by HTML5 UP</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100italic,300,300italic,400,400italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="https://www.dropbox.com/sh/b7bqyva7pz39nx1/QIGR6hJpkM/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="https://www.dropbox.com/sh/b7bqyva7pz39nx1/QIGR6hJpkM/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.dropbox.com/sh/b7bqyva7pz39nx1/QIGR6hJpkM/skel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>
    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.dropbox.com/sh/b7bqyva7pz39nx1/QIGR6hJpkM/skel-noscript.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.dropbox.com/sh/b7bqyva7pz39nx1/QIGR6hJpkM/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.dropbox.com/sh/b7bqyva7pz39nx1/QIGR6hJpkM/style-wide.css" />
    </noscript>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.dropbox.com/sh/b7bqyva7pz39nx1/QIGR6hJpkM/v8.css" /><![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.dropbox.com/sh/b7bqyva7pz39nx1/QIGR6hJpkM/v9.css" /><![endif]--
```

Answer (score 23):

Replace `www.` with `dl.` is what worked for me.

Something like this:  `https://dl.dropbox.com/s/...`

Comment: This gives me a 403 (access denied). I am currently not logged into Dropbox, which most users probably won't be.

Answer (score 3):

Copy the link by Clicking on "Share" and add ?raw=1 after every JS and CSS file or other files that you want to host on Dropbox.

```
<script src='https://www.dropbox.com/s/example.js?raw=1' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Reference: https://docs.helpscout.net/article/92-stylesheet-dropbox

Copy the public link of your file and then replace `www` with `dl` and it should work. I tried it, its working, here is the JS file link with the code -

```
<script src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/au8i66el92duxdm/homeslider.js'></script>
```

Comment: Add the code to the answer please. This is making it hard to get the answer and it may go invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Im getting a 404 on your links which means your files are probably only accessible to you when your logged in. To stop this you will need to use the dropbox public link

To do this go to your file in dropbox and right-click your CSS file and select Copy Public Link. This will copy a direct URL for your CSS file to your clipboard which should work

Comment: I even tried it with public folder in Google Drive but the theme is not being applied. I'm unable to figure out the problem. I'm struck with this problem since a couple of days ago. I've been Googling since then, but I found no solution :(

Comment: Is the site online anywhere ? Would be alot easier to diagnose the prob

Comment: Sorry. I haven't yet hosted it in my blog. I'm still experimenting and messing with the HTML file

Answer (score 0):

Put the files in your public folder and then copy public link.

[See this article about hosting files on dropbox](https://web.archive.org/web/20140206103510/http://www.fiveforblogger.com/2012/04/host-css-files-using-dropbox.html)

Comment: I tried it several times using SkyDrive, Dropbox and Google Drive, but I end up with failure and I'm unable to figure out the nature of the problem. But the template works fine when I refer the css and js from my local drive.

Comment: In dropbox have you put all the files in the public folder?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem using images and fonts in the Public Folder, which I had scripted correctly using the Copy Public Link. Then I checked Properties of the Dropbox Public Folder, for some reason the "Read Only" Box was shaded. I clicked off it, and then was able to get Blogger to upload from the Public Folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try `dl.dropboxusercontent.com` instead of `www.dropbox.com`

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm not at all familiar with dropbox, but the other answer said to use `dl.dropbox.com`, not `dl.dropboxusercontent.com`. Not sure if that makes any difference...